# Configuring label attributes in Graph Viewer

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

When creating graphs for viewing in the ArangoDB Web Interface, I am having some issues with labels for Vertices and Edges:

1. I can only set Vertex/Edge attributes to simple keys. I cannot get deeper object references working.
   e.g. a vertex label attribute of `name` is valid, but `info.firstName` or `info["firstName"]` are not, even though the value is on the vertex. The graph displays `ATTR NOT SET` if I use object references
2. When programmatically creating a Graph, I don't know how to set:

   1. Vertices labels
   2. Vertices Coloring attributes
   3. Edge Labels

When creating a graph with Node.js and the arangojs npm package, I use the `graph.create` command, for example:

```
  var graph = db.graph('myGraph');
  graph.create({
      edgeDefinitions: [
        {
          collection: 'myEdges',
          from: [
            'myNodes'
          ],
          to: [
            'myNodes'
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
```

Is there a way to fully configure the graph for proper formatting in the ArangoDB Web Interface? I can't seem to find any other function in the libraries that would let me do this.

I destroy and recreate graphs all the time and it would be great to fully create a configured graph, referencing objects within the vertex (and edges) for labels.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curerntly the settings of the graph viewer are only stored to the browsers local storage. Thus they're not persisted. Changing this is on the list of feature requests for the graph viewer overhaul.

So at the time being the answer is: its not possible. I will add the deep object selection you mention to the feature list. Once its possible, I will edit this.

Comment: Thanks for that @dothebart, being able to provide default graph visualisation settings will help when writing code that migrates data into ArangoDB.